# Получить количество товаров в выборке категории Virtuemart

Tags: mysql, select, virtuemart

Пишу модуль поиска для Virtuemart, фришек не нашел, пайды не по карману...
Таким запросом вытягиваю список категории и айдишку для каждой

```
SELECT virtuemart_category_id, category_name FROM #__virtuemart_categories_ru_ru
```

Как присоединить таблицу #__virtuemart_product_categories, у которой колонка    virtuemart_product_id содержит айдишки товаров, а колонка virtuemart_category_id содержит айдишки категории, приложил скрин таблицы, ЧТОБЫ получить в том же запросе помимо названия категории+айди еще и количество товаров для каждой категории??
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]